# Syncing Cloudformation stack with template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have some cloudformation stacks created from a centralized CF template in multiple AWS Accounts. I have a need to sync the Cloudformation stacks in all such accounts based on any updates in the template. One possible solution is currently to periodically poll for updates in the template and sync them using a scheduled Lambda or so. But does AWS already provide a capability for this already or what would be the most elegant way to implement this ?

Answer (score 2):

The use case you describe is covered by stack sets: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/what-is-cfnstacksets.html.

It works best if your accounts are in an [organisation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_introduction.html): .  because then you can manage everything through stacksets.

Outside an org you need to [use "self-managed" permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacksets-prereqs-self-managed.html), which requires some manual setup. the main time consuming piece is going into each target account to make a role for you ([example template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-stackset-sample-templates-us-east-1/AWSCloudFormationStackSetAdministrationRole.yml.))

Comment: In this case I cannot add the accounts under an org since they don't belong together.

Comment: added some info on the permissions you need outside of organisations

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be provided by [CloudFormation Git Sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/git-sync.html) which monitors a git repository for changes and updates the stack accordingly:

> When you commit changes to the template or the deployment file, CloudFormation automatically updates the stack. This way, you can use pull requests and version tracking to configure, deploy, and update your CloudFormation stacks from a centralized location.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).